# Net Core And Ajax - Select2 Returned null

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, jquery-select2

I want to post the selected values ​​in select2 with ajax. But on the controller side, the values ​​return empty.

```
<script>

    function UpdateCities() {

        var cities = $("#selected-cities").val();

        $.ajax({
            url: "/Admin/MyBusinesses/UpdateCities",
            data: cities,
            type: "Get",
            success: function () {
                
            }
        })

    }

</script>
```

[image: and photo]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to post the selected values ​​in select2 with ajax. But on the
> controller side, the values ​​return empty.

You are getting empty result because of mismatched key value pairs which is cities and lack of proper serialization as MVC controller doesn't recognize FormBody by default whilst API controller can.

Therefore, numerous ways available to overcome the issue. However, the easiest way is to pass param in controller with parameter name along with  [traditional: true](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings) which will enable serialization which is currently missing.

Correct Way:

```
 function UpdateCities() {
        alert("click");
       /* var cities = $("#selected-cities").val();*/
        var cities = [34, 50]
        console.log(cities);
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Admin/MyBusinesses/UpdateCities",
            type: "Get",
            data: {
                cities: cities
            },
            traditional: true,
            success: function () {

            }
        })

    }
```

Output:

[image]

**Note:** You can get [more details here in Jquery Official Document](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings).

Comment: Thanks for your response and glad to assist you.